# Scripts.Render is not adding the v= parameter to my scripts

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, bundle

I have a weird behavior. I have two different ScriptBundles, like this:

```
var b1 = new ScriptBundle("~/bundle/js").Include(
"~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
"~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
"~/Scripts/jquery.validate*",
"~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"
//plus all other 3rd party scripts
);
bundles.Add(b1);
var bLicensingDC = new ScriptBundle("~/bundle/licensing-dc/js").Include(
"~/App/licensing-dc-built.js");
bundles.Add(bLicensingDC);
```

Both bundles are added using `@Scripts.Render("...")`, but only the `~/bundle/js` one renders with the cache buster `v=` parameter.

```
<script src="/bundle/js?v=-5GM9HLcujnDGm6SNVq0Es63_cXK2viQ4_nYEpm02Ls1"></script>
<script src="/bundle/licensing-dc/js"></script>
```

Why? Does the location of the javascript files have anything to do with this?

Comment: FYI, i'm trying to find the source code for System.Web.Optimization, but it appears to not be available just yet.

Comment: They claim it'll be available soon. they're probably trying to fix some mess.

Comment: When you navigate to `bundle/licensing-dc/js`, what's the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

False alarm, this was user error. I was doing the following:

```
@{
    string jsPath = Url.Content("~/bundle/licensing-" + ViewBag.JurisdictionPath + "/js");
}

@section scripts {
    @Scripts.Render(jsPath)
}
```

because the jsPath is dynamically constructed based on some other factors. Removing the `Url.Content("...");` resolved my issue.